# Dynamically update highchart series in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, highcharts

I'm trying to set a page with one single chart and two series to display according to the user's choice.
So basically, one page, one chart, two options representing the data to display.

I'm stuck when i need to access the chart's series array.

Here's my simplified example:

**chart.html**

```
<template name="ChartWithDifferentSeries">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Example</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a href="#" class="displaySerie1 btn btn-default">Serie 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="displaySerie2 btn btn-default">Serie 2</a>
            </div>
            {{> highchartsHelper chartId="chart" chartWidth="100%" charHeight="100%" chartObject=chartMultiSeries}}
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

**chart.js**

```
var serie1 = [['share 1',25],['share 2',75]];
var serie2 = [['share 1',10],['share 2',30],['share 3',60]];

var serieToDisplay= 1;

function buildData(){
    return serieToDisplay === 1?serie1:serie2;
}

Template.ChartWithDifferentSeries.helpers({
    chartMultiSeries: function () {
        return {
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                data: buildData()
            }]
        };
    }
})

Template.ChartWithDifferentSeries.events({
    "click .displaySerie1": function () {
        serieToDisplay=1;
        var series = chart.highcharts().series[0];
        series.setData(buildData());
    },
    "click .displaySerie2": function () {
        serieToDisplay=2;
        var series = chart.highcharts().series[0];
        series.setData(buildData());
    }
})
```

Note: i'm using the MaazAli/Meteor-HighCharts wrapper. Maybe that's what causing me to get confused.

**Console Error at the moment: highcharts() is not a function.**

### BUGFIX

I changed

```
chart.highcharts().series[0]
```

by

```
$('#chart').highcharts().series[0]
```

it's all right now. still i'm wondering if i respect best practises doing that...

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, charts.highcharts() is not a function. Access it like this:

```
chart.series[0].data
```